# EF Core 3.1 : I do not understand a configuration error from scaffolded code

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have the following error et runtime that I do not understand:

> The relationship from 'GpsBoxSubTypeDes.GpsBox' to 'GpsBoxSubType.GpsBoxSubTypeDes' with foreign key properties {'GpsBoxTypeId' : int, 'GpsBoxSubTypeId' : int} cannot target the primary key {'GpsBoxSubTypeId' : int} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.

The scaffolding code and configuration for these two entities is the following:

```
    public partial class GpsBoxSubType
    {
        public GpsBoxSubType()
        {
            Vehicule = new HashSet<Vehicule>();
            AdditionalInit();
        }
        public int GpsBoxTypeId { get; set; }
        public int GpsBoxSubTypeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int IconId { get; set; }

        public virtual GpsBoxType GpsBoxType { get; set; }
        public virtual Icon Icon { get; set; }
        public virtual GpsBoxSubTypeDes GpsBoxSubTypeDes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Vehicule> Vehicule { get; set; }
}

builder.Entity<GpsBoxSubType>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.GpsBoxTypeId, e.GpsBoxSubTypeId });

    entity.Property(e => e.GpsBoxTypeId).HasColumnName("GpsBoxTypeID");

    entity.Property(e => e.GpsBoxSubTypeId).HasColumnName("GpsBoxSubTypeID");

    entity.Property(e => e.IconId).HasDefaultValueSql("((33554432))");

    entity.Property(e => e.Name)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(50);

    entity.HasOne(d => d.GpsBoxType)
        .WithMany(p => p.GpsBoxSubType)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.GpsBoxTypeId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_GpsBoxSubType_GpsBoxTypeID");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.Icon)
        .WithMany(p => p.GpsBoxSubType)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.IconId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_GpsBoxSubType_IconId");
});

public partial class GpsBoxSubTypeDes
{
   public int GpsBoxTypeId { get; set; }
   public int GpsBoxSubTypeId { get; set; }
   public int Lcid { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }

   public virtual GpsBoxSubType GpsBox { get; set; }
}

builder.Entity<GpsBoxSubTypeDes>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.GpsBoxTypeId, e.GpsBoxSubTypeId });

    entity.Property(e => e.GpsBoxTypeId).HasColumnName("GpsBoxTypeID");

    entity.Property(e => e.GpsBoxSubTypeId).HasColumnName("GpsBoxSubTypeID");

    entity.Property(e => e.Description)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(50)
        .IsUnicode(false);

    entity.Property(e => e.Lcid).HasColumnName("LCId");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.GpsBox)
        .WithOne(p => p.GpsBoxSubTypeDes)
        .HasForeignKey<GpsBoxSubTypeDes>(d => new { d.GpsBoxTypeId, d.GpsBoxSubTypeId })
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_GpsBoxSubTypeDes_GpsBoxSubType");
});
```

EDIT: added missing entity and configuation:

```
 public partial class GpsBoxType
    {
        public GpsBoxType()
        {
            GpsBoxConfiguration = new HashSet<GpsBoxConfiguration>();
            GpsBoxSubType = new HashSet<GpsBoxSubType>();
            GpsBoxTypeDetail = new HashSet<GpsBoxTypeDetail>();
            Vehicule = new HashSet<Vehicule>();

            AdditionalInit();
        }

        [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
        public int GpsBoxTypeId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Order = 3)]
        public int Category { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Order = 4)]
        public int IconId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Order = 5)]
        public GpsBoxTypeDes GpsBoxTypeDes { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Order = 6)]
        public virtual ICollection<GpsBoxConfiguration> GpsBoxConfiguration { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Order = 8)]
        public virtual ICollection<GpsBoxSubType>
GpsBoxSubType { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Order = 9)]
        public virtual ICollection<GpsBoxTypeDetail>
GpsBoxTypeDetail { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Order = 10)]
        public Icon Icon { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Order = 11)]
        public virtual ICollection<Vehicule> Vehicule { get; set; }
}

            builder.Entity<GpsBoxType>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.GpsBoxTypeId)
                    .HasColumnName("GpsBoxTypeID")
                    .ValueGeneratedNever();

                entity.Property(e => e.Category).HasDefaultValueSql("((1))");

                entity.Property(e => e.IconId).HasDefaultValueSql("((33554432))");

                entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(50);

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Icon)
                    .WithMany(p => p.GpsBoxType)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.IconId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_GpsBoxType_Icon");
```

EDIT 2:
Here is the stack trace that shows what I was expecting, EF is using conventions and not the condifugration.

```
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateNoShadowKeys(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Internal.SqlServerModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ValidatingConvention.ProcessModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder, IConventionContext`1 context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.FinalizeModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.FinalizeModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.CheckState()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalQueryableExtensions.FromSqlRaw[TEntity](DbSet`1 source, String sql, Object[] parameters)
   at RTE.Technologies.SafeProtect.Common.Data.DataBridge.Core.RegistrationDataBridge.GetDevicesToRetrogradeToAuthorizedStatus() in D:\AzureDevops\SafeProtect.Common\SafeProtect.Common.Data\DataBridge\Core\RegistrationDataBridge.cs:line 171
   at RTE.Technologies.SafeProtect.Common.DummyConsole.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\AzureDevops\SafeProtect.Common\SafeProtect.Common.Data.ConsoleTest\Program.cs:line 57
```

So it is likely the problem is on my side.

EDIT 3: The error was indeed on my side, I was not calling the configuration for the GpsBoxSubType entity 8=|

Comment: You cant reference Composite key/FK via a singular FK/key. this is likely the problem  `.HasForeignKey(d => d.GpsBoxTypeId)` though its a little unclear what you intend to do here

Comment: This FK is for another entity which was missing from the code above. Fixed. Anyway I do not understand why scaffolded code is failing. I've not written the configuration by hand. This comes from the SQL provider